# Why do I install ffmpeg-python error via pip, python on version 3.9.13 and pip on version 22.2.1

Tags: python, ffmpeg

```
$ pip3 install ffmpeg-python
Collecting ffmpeg-python
  Using cached ffmpeg_python-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 829.2/829.2 kB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 24, in <module>
          from setuptools.depends import Require
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in <module>
          from .py33compat import Bytecode
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 54, in <module>
          unescape = getattr(html, 'unescape', html_parser.HTMLParser().unescape)
      AttributeError: 'HTMLParser' object has no attribute 'unescape'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyowl.jpg)

Comment: What would you expect? What even is your question, is it just the one from the title? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry I'm a new user so I don't understand how to add a topic

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me.

Python version - 3.7.1,
pip version - 22.1.2